# Child emit does not update v-model prop Array of parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model, vue-reactivity

I'm using this parent component:

```
<template>
  <div id="cms-custom-editor" class="cms-custom-editor">
    <cms-editor-toolbar v-model:toggles="state.toggles"/>
    <div class="content">Toggle Buttons: {{ state.toggles }}</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import CmsEditorToolbar from './cms-editor-toolbar.vue'
import {reactive, ref} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
    toggles: [],
})
</script>
```

to pass down `state.toggles` as a prop to the `cms-editor-toolbar` child component:

```
<template>
  <div id="cms-editor-toolbar" class="cms-editor-toolbar">
    <button @click="toggleButton"></button>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
    toggles: Array,
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:toggles'])

const toggleButton = () => {
    // ... logic to determine toggleAction
    console.log(toggleAction) // logs correct toggleAction
    emit('update:toggles', toggleAction) //emits only first toggleAction and no other
}

</script>
```

For whatever reason `emit('update:toggles', toggleAction)` only emits the first `toggleAction` to the parent. For every other change, the `state.toggles` array is not updated.

From the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70101927/why-is-vue-v-model-not-working-for-an-array-prop), I've tried using `ref` instead of `reactive`:

```
<template>
  <div id="cms-custom-editor" class="cms-custom-editor">
    <cms-editor-toolbar v-model:toggles="toggles"/>
    <div class="content">Toggle Buttons: {{ toggles }}</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import CmsEditorToolbar from './cms-editor-toolbar.vue'
import {reactive, ref} from "vue";

const toggles = ref([1,2,3])
</script>
```

but it changes nothing. Again the array is only updated once and no consecutive action has any effect. How do I make this work?

**Edit:**

I've added additional props (not arrays) to sibling elements inside the child, which not only are emitted correctly, but also trigger all actions of the `array emit`. Basically it seems to save the array inside the child until the emit is triggered by a sibling emit, which sends the complete array to the parent. No idea how this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the wrong method to check if `state.toggles` is updated. Rendering it in a paragraph usually works, but in this case it doesn't seem to be rerendered for whatever reason.

Logging the array inside the parent like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(state.toggles)
}, 1000);
```

shows that it is indeed updating. The emits are working.